# { % extends parent _ template|default:"base.html" % } vs {% extends "base.html" %} in Django?

Tags: django

What is the difference between { % extends parent _ template|default:"base.html" % } vs {% extends "base.html" %} in template inheritance in django ? I've seen both being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ % extends parent_template|default:"base.html" % }` if have `parent_template`, it will extend it. If not , it will extend `base.html`

`{% extends "base.html" %}`always extend `base.html`.

Its different